# RestKit / AFNetworking - Send only one request at a time (queue)

Tags: ios, objective-c, rest, afnetworking, restkit

I'm using RestKit / AFNetworking to communicate with a private api. This API is returning a cookie with a sessionID on every call. If you do a call with an already used sessionID it will return an error. So every sessionID can only be used once.

The issue is that when sending two request at the same time, one will fail as they both are sent with the same sessionID in the cookie.

Is there a way to make RestKit / AFNetworking only perform my calls after the last call has returned with the next sessionID?
I'd like to be able to just send the calls but have them delayed after the last call has succeeded or failed.

Comment: Make a second call on success or failure block of call in afnetworking.

Comment: Yes, right. That works. But I don't really want to do that as api calls can happen on user input. And I cannot foresee what the user is doing in which order. I also don't really want to build a queueing system of my own.

Comment: Is the cookie set automatically or you need to do something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is exactly what NSOperationQueue is for:

Init an NSOperationQueue and set number of concurrent tasks to 1:

```
NSOperationQueue *queue = [NSOperationQueue new];
queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1;
```

Be sure to retain a reference to the queue, or it will be deallocated.

To add your HTTP calls to the queue, you'll have to subclass NSOperation.  Write your subclasses so each NSOperation instance makes a *synchronous* HTTP request in the operation's -main method, then sets the session ID for the next operation:

```
-(void)main {
// read the previous session ID
NSString *sessionID = [MyDataSingleton sharedInstance].sessionID;

//make synchronous call
...

//Set the session ID for the next operation
[MyDataSingleton sharedInstance].sessionID = sessionID;
```